# How to flick an object

Tags: android, gesture

Is there documentation or an API that allows for an object to be flicked in a certain direction, such as a button? I've tried using 'drag & drop' to try and emulate this feature but not with the same results.

Here is an example: http://youtu.be/J-83lssy5kA?t=1m47s

Basically, you can see the guy flick the chat-head towards the close icon to close the chat. The same features are found in android launchers where you can flick to remove an icon fromthe home screen. Are those gestures custom built or is it an API, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flick` that you are talking about is called `fling` officially. Yes, you can handle fling events using the Android API by having your activity implement the [`GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) interface.   This interface will let you handle all the common gestures like scroll, long press, fling and so on. In your case, the `onFling()` method will be called.

However, in your case you only want the fling gesture in which case you will have to subclass [`GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) and override methods selectively.

For more, please refer the docs: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: Ok, I got the detector working, but currently the `onTouchEvent()` method that starts the gesture detection applies to the whole screen, how can I make it apply only a single object, such as a button or `TextView`

Comment: Then you need `GestureOverlayView`. See this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGestures/article.html

Comment: Figured it out. simply needed to do `textView.setOnTouchListener()` but after implementing this, I cannot get velocity data from the `onFlick()` method. Methods such as `onDown()` and `onLong()` still work fine though.

Comment: Ach, silly me. I had 
`        textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        });`
And just needed to change the return to `return true`. Thanks for your help, marked as solved.

Comment: Okay so you are implementing the gesture listener and passing the `MotionEvent` to the gesture detector when the `onTouch` happens, right?

Comment: Yep, pass the `MotionEvent`from `onTouch` from the `setOnTouchListener` to `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);` within the `onTouch`. Just remember to set the return of the `onTouch` to `True`, otherwise, it never initiates any gesture functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I noticed this.
I recently tried to find a coding for the same but never could and lost interest. But this is what I feel is the solution:-
In a quick time interval find 2 points cordinates of that flicking action( drag)
Then project a third point according to the slope of this line equation.
Keep updating the position of the view you flicked while you make it travel slowly from point2 to projected point3 via may be a slow loop or timer

For slope you have 
    (y1-y2)/(x1-x2)